# How to read object properties from ontology using Jena Java API

Tags: java, api, jena, owl, ontology

I have opened my ontology so far and now I want to read all the objects and display their properties:

I have the next code:

```
// Opening the ontology.
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
model.read("file:C:/Users/Antonio/Desktop/myOntology.owl","OWL");


// Going through the ontology
for (Iterator<OntClass> i = model.listClasses();i.hasNext();){
    OntClass cls = i.next();
    System.out.print(cls.getLocalName()+": ");

    // here I want to show the properties
}
```

which just shows the name of the classes, but not their properties.
I have been reading the documentation but I don't find anything useful.

Hopefully someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want all the properties but you can do that easily. First of all make sure to import Jena's OntProperty `import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntProperty;`

Then you can simply inside your for loop : `cls.listDeclaredProperties().toList()`

If you want to access the content of a specific property though you could do it this way :
Check your `.owl` file for the URI which generally looks something like this `"http://example.com/ontology#"`

So your Java code is going to look like this : `OntProperty nameOfProperty = model.getOntProperty("http://example.com/ontology#nameOfyourProperty");`

Then inside your loop you could do for example something like this : `cls.getProperty(nameOfProperty).getString()`

And by the way before reading your file you might want to put it in a try catch statement. Hope that helped.

Comment: Your code is valid when you know the names of the properties...but what if you do not know them? how could you do it?

Comment: The first part of my answer is what you're looking for. If you do a `System.out.println(cls.listDeclaredProperties().toList())` it will print all the properties of your file.

Answer (score 0):

The code is printing classes because `listClasses()` returns classes of the ontology. For printing the object properties of the individuals, you can use OWL API